# How to import Manzana C# library

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, dll

I am trying *to build an application to grab **syslog** from ios device*. 
I am completely new to C# and have no idea on where to start.

I have found *library* called **Manzana**, a *C# library* to obtain device control of ios device.

My problem is I do not know **how to load this library** or **how the calling conventions** are.

Is there anyone kind enough to explain what steps i need to take ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend you to use a working iTunesMobileDevice C# API.
There are hundred versions of Manzana that are either out of date or include crap code (Non-working `DllImports` or obsolete methods).

**Do not use Manzana**, it's outdated and contains crap-code.

I recommend a powerful MobileDevice-Version: (Chinese comments but clean & working code):

[Working iTunesMobileDevice C# API](https://github.com/nivalxer/MobileDevice/)

Once you downloaded the source-files (All .cs files), drag them into your IDE's project. Open your main class and make an instance of **iPhone**.
You need to create 2 event-handlers, **Connect** & **Disconnect**

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
iPhone my_device_instance = new iPhone();
my_device_instance.Connect += new ConnectEventHandler(onConnect);
my_device_instance.Disconnect += new ConnectEventHandler(onDisconnect);
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for device...");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1)
}

static void onConnect(object sender, ConnectEventArgs e)
{
// Do stuff...
}

static void onDisconnect(object sender, ConnectEventArgs e)
{
// Do stuff...
}
```

Learn the basics of C# and analyse the given source-code. 
One more thing: If you want to grab syslog, you need to make use of the class `iPhoneFile`.